# MVVM command binding error

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, telerik, silverlight-5.0

My command binding is not fire, but it worked as expected with another button.
My Xaml,

```
<telerik:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="TagTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Tags_CustmFldDetails.TagsList}" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">               
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TagName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <telerik:RadRibbonButton  Command="{Binding DataContext.Tags_CustmFldDetails.DeleteTags_CustmFldCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" SmallImage="../Images/delete_icon.png" />
        </StackPanel>
    </telerik:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Command for RadRibbonButton not firing,
Error is,

> System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error:
>   'Tags_CustmFldDetails' property not found on
>   'ChurchHub.Server.ReqResp.DTO.PlannerTagSerializable'
>   'ChurchHub.Server.ReqResp.DTO.PlannerTagSerializable'
>   (HashCode=55932620). BindingExpression:
>   Path='Tags_CustmFldDetails.TagsList'
>   DataItem='ChurchHub.Server.ReqResp.DTO.PlannerTagSerializable'
>   (HashCode=55932620); target element is
>   'Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadTreeViewItem' (Name=''); target property
>   is 'ItemsSource' (type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable')..

This command work perfectly in out side of this "HierarchicalDataTemplate".
Try using adding

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.Tags_CustmFldDetails.DeleteTags_CustmFldCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}
```

But nothing happened, same error.
"Tags_CustmFldDetails" is command hosted view model.
How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry... I just change Ancestor type. now its working.
In my button,

```
<telerik:RadRibbonButton  Command="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=UserControl},Path=DataContext.Tags_CustmFldDetails.DeleteTags_CustmFldCommand}" 
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding}" 
                                      SmallImage="../Images/delete_icon.png" 
                                      />
```

I change relative source binding.